# Watch a URL in a tab and block it so it doesn't get called or alter it before it is sent

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to block a URL to be called by giving the URL address, something like:

This doesn't work but something like this.

```
$.watch("http://www.test.com/alter.php",function(){
    //It was called here
    return false; //This in this scenario would block the URL to be called, it would cancel its request, it wouldn't even send the request, it would cancel before it access the web.
});
```

is it possible to block a URL so it doesn't get called or alter its request before its called in a tab via the Google Extensions?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use chrome.webRequest's [onBeforeRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest) method in blocking mode to cancel navigations.

Your manifest will need to declare permissions for "webRequest" and "webRequestBlocking".

Then add a background script that hooks onBeforeRequest and cancels the navigation for that URL only:

```
chrome.extension.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function() { return {cancel: true} },
  { urls: ["http://www.test.com/alter.php"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Navigation seems to happen though. Requests aren't sent, but the UI portion of the browser will still "try to navigate". ie, a "This webpage was blocked by an extension" error appears